# AVQueuePlayer sometimes moves to the next AVPlayerItem in its items queue without sending AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification

Tags: iphone, ios4, avfoundation, http-live-streaming, avplayer

I'm using `AVQueuePlayer` to play a couple of streams in order. But often the `AVQueuePlayer` decides to skip to the next song without sending `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification`. Also no error is logged in the player. The streaming protocol used is Http Live Streaming. Could this behavoir be due to a problem with the streams? Has anyone else encountered it?

Comment: Did it send a `AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTimeNotification`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the status of the item that didn't play? It may have failed, for some reason.